# How to move objects in Unity VR Toolkit (Raycast) corretly?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, toolkit

i'm really stuck with some kind of a more basic problem.
i want to recreate a feature in oculus home for my own apartment project, where i can place and especially move / turn furniture with my vr controller (raycast around).

at this moment, i can move the furniture while snapping the transform.position of the object to the raycastHit.position. while implementing an offset, i can hit the object where ever i want and move it.
The problem:

1. The object ignores other surfaces like walls and floors while moving. (the rigedbody ignores colliders).
2. I can't increase the distance of the raycast, because it is snaped to the objects position. therefore i can only decrease the distance while movinge the pointer towards me, but not away from me.

This video shows the behaviour.
[Youtube Video Capture from scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVfT3p5gbQc)

This is the code so far.
On the right RayController a script to pass the not needed currently needed position and the hitPoint.position to the selected object

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using UnityEngine.XR.Interaction.Toolkit;

public class ControllerPosition : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputActionProperty positionProperty;
    [SerializeField] XRRayInteractor rayController;

    public Vector3 Position { get; private set; } = Vector3.zero;
    public Vector3 rayHitPosition { get; private set; } = Vector3.zero;


    private void Awake()
    {
        rayController = GetComponent<XRRayInteractor>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (rayController.TryGetHitInfo(out var hitPosition, out var hitNormal, out _, out _))
        {
            rayHitPosition = hitPosition;
        }

        Position = positionProperty.action.ReadValue<Vector3>();
    }
}
```

This is the code for the dragable object

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.Interaction.Toolkit;

public class DragObject : XRGrabInteractable
{
    [SerializeField] XRRayInteractor ray;

    private Vector3 mOffset;

    private ControllerPosition controllerPosition = null;

    protected override void Awake()
    {
        base.Awake();
    }

    protected override void OnSelectEntered(SelectEnterEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnSelectEntered(args);
        controllerPosition = args.interactor.GetComponent<ControllerPosition>();

        mOffset = gameObject.transform.position - controllerPosition.rayHitPosition;
    }

    protected override void OnSelectExited(SelectExitEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnSelectExited(args);
        controllerPosition = null;
    }

    public override void ProcessInteractable(XRInteractionUpdateOrder.UpdatePhase updatePhase)
    {
        base.ProcessInteractable(updatePhase);

        if (isSelected)
        {
            if (updatePhase == XRInteractionUpdateOrder.UpdatePhase.Dynamic)
            {
                UpdateObjectPosition();
            }
        }
    }

    private void UpdateObjectPosition()
    {
        Vector3 position = controllerPosition ? controllerPosition.Position : Vector3.zero;
        
        transform.position = controllerPosition.rayHitPosition + mOffset;

    }
}
```

Any advices?

best regards

Comment: I would suggest changing the movement type to velocity tracking. That will allow for the rigidbody to check for collisions. As far as getting the distance to work, I would try using a seperate ray than the one being used for object detection, or ignore the grab tag/layer during the raycast when you are already selecting an object.